# Emergency ad-hoc network using home computer wifi

Tags: routing, home-networking

Power is out here, across the region. (minor, expect it on in 2 hrs) If I power the fiber-modem with my ups, I can get a connection. If I set my apple to 'share internet connection' across WiFi, I become a node.

Is there a setting a neighbor can use on their wifi to share their connection with me? Essentially become a neighborhood network?

Comment: Sorry. I'll drop the 'networking' tag if I can.

Comment: I found 'olsrd', an adhoc wireless mesh routing daemon, that looks like it would do the trick. A bit beyond super user, and on to server-fault, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the last answer, if you are using a Mac, I am clueless and can't help you.

I would recommend you use [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/), it should allow you to do what you want!

Answer (score 0):

I'd want to be rather careful about packets on that network... but most WiFi adapters have an ad-hoc mode.  On OS X, it's "Create Network..." in the WiFi menu.  I couldn't tell you off the top of my head where to find it on Windows (not least because every computer vendor seems to ship their own WiFi manager).

Anyway, one person creates the ad-hoc network, other people can scan for and join ad-hoc networks or you can share the SSID around.

Comment: Nope. Tried it. I (eg the neighbor) can't share a WiFi connection over WiFi.

Comment: Mm, I think I misunderstood the requirements, then.  You would need two WiFi transceivers for what i think you're describing.  USB WiFi is fairly cheap if you don't insist on 802.11n; but I notice Best Buy has [refurbs](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/D-Link+-+Factory-Refurbished+Wireless-N+150+USB+Adapter/2095595.p?id=1218309075636&skuId=2095595&st=usb%20wifi&cp=1&lp=9) for $20.  Of course, it's probably too late now.

Comment: Fail, then. So, there is no 'store the packets then send em out over the same WiFi' router software within reach of an ambitious noob?

Comment: Not really.  It might be possible to cozen OpenWRT into doing it, but then you need a compatible router and need to flash it (and it's not especially newbie-friendly.  Heck, I'm afraid to try it and I'm far from "newbie").

Comment: got it. Requires -two- laptops at each 'node', connect them by ethernet cable, one shares incoming wifi to ethernet, other shares ethernet to new wifi. Voila, emergency ad-hoc network nodes.